# Big Query: Does it talke longer to query if my data is in Nearline storage class of Google Cloud Storage (vs Standard)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Assume you have a csv file in Google Cloud Storage. It is cheaper to use the Nearline (or Coldline etc) storage class than the standard class. I want to read data using Big Query but would it take longer to query (or cost extra) if I save my file in the Nearline storage class than I do the Standard storage class?

Answer (score 3):

As you can find in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes), the access latency of file in standard, nearline, coldline or archive storage classe is the same.

There are 2 differences:

1. The cost: colder storage cost less at rest, but you pay for reading the data. No difference between BigQuery and other way to access the file.
2. Tye service availability (99.95% with standard, 99.9% with other storage class)

Answer (score 0):

The comment above would be the correct info, but I think that if you are trying to compare between which architecture would be cheaper then depends also on How many reads you are planning to do each month.

As the comment above mentioned, Nearline or Coldline are cheaper for storage but you pay for reading the data, so you need kinda a do some calculus.

Data queried ( BQ planning quota, current cost $5.00 per TB after the 1st TB) + Price of the Data Stored ( Standard $0.020, Nearline $0.010, and Coldline $0.004 x GB respectively ) + Retrieving Data price (  Standard  $0.05, Nearline $0.10*, Coldline $0.10*, per 10, 000 operations ).

So if you querying the 2 TB of data in 1 month,
Retrieving them in 10 operations,
You may get something like: $ 5 (from BQ) + $0.1 (10 ops) +  $20  ( 2TB storage ) in a Neraline GCS.

- This could be in the us-central region and also without taking into account free operations or discounts.

Suggest you to do some calculus : https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?hl=en